# Publication estimated time

Tags: publications

What is the difference between "Estimated publication date" and "publication due date"? For example:

```
Estimated publication date: 8 weeks
Due publication date: After positive completion of peer-review process
```

Answer (score 1):

"Estimated publication date" - we have not set a fixed date for publishing this article, but this is a guess based on how long we think it's going to take.

"Due publication date" - we have set a fixed date for publishing this article.

In this case, I'd guess that they haven't yet reviewed the article (so can't be sure they're going to publish it) but know from experience that it usually takes about eight weeks to review + publish. When it's been reviewed, they'll be able to set a due date.